# How do versioned views work with multiple editors?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, database, versioning

I understand that in the database environment, by executing

`version_util.set_current_version('version1')`

Editor1 is able to write SQL statements against [table_name]_vw views to edit the data at version1.

But if Editor2 (from another workstation) executes

`version_util.set_current_version('version2')`

the [table_name]_vw views should be populated with the data at version2, right? In this case, if Editor1 run a query against the [table_name]_vw, will he still get the data at version1? Or is he still editing the right version?

Comment: Is this GIS related?

Comment: The "version" here is geodatabase version

Answer (score 2):

You are correct on both concepts.

1. A query of a specific named version via SQL will always only see the edits made within that named version per the last edit or reconcile/post operation, as you're really just pointing to a state.
2. The other editor connecting to a different named version is querying a separate transactional version and/or instantiating a separate edit session.

To quote the documentation:

> You can only edit one version per edit session. For example, if you
>   want to edit a second version (such as mynewedits), you must close the
>   edit session on myedits12111, as shown in this step. Then you could
>   execute set_current_version to point to version mynewedits, then start
>   an edit session on it by executing edit_version.

Editing versioned data in Oracle using SQL (Other RDBMS use same concept)

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/in_Oracle/006z000000vm000000/

The procedure version_util.set_current_version followed by procedure version_user_ddl.edit_version can potentially lock the delta tables if there are uncommitted edits, assuming both of your edit sessions are editing the same object via the versioned view.

It is recommended to commit as soon as an edit is completed as to maintain a lock on the transactional version you are currently editing as but NOT on the entire A or D table that stores the changes.